# Derivative of vector with respect to change in length

Tags: derivatives

I want to ask a question about derivatives. Say I have a vector $\mathbf{r}$, for example in radial direction. Now I change the length, thus the new length is the old length plus a change. Is it possible to take a derivative with respect to the change in the length somehow, so that the result is a vector?

Comment: This is far too broad to be answerable. What kind of vector space are you in? What do you mean by radial direction? Derivative of what kind?

Comment: Ah sorry, what I forgot. I have a scalar function $f(\vert \mathbf{r} \vert)$ and I want to take the derivative of this function with respect to the change in the length. It is all in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Radial direction is in the direction of the polar unit vector, but that is not really important for me. Could be any direction

Comment: @Q.stion Better put every explanation in the main body of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state in the comments, you have some function $$f \left(|\mathbf r| \right),$$ and you would like to know if you could take some sort of derivative of this, so that you have another vector.

Well, since you also say you're in $\mathrm R^3,$ then we can write $\mathbf r=(x,y,z).$ Then we have that $f=f(x,y,z).$ Thus what you want is the gradient of $f,$ which you can calculate as $$\left(\partial f_x,\partial f_y,\partial f_z\right).$$